# Compare the contents of two files and output the the differences in contents along with line numbers

Tags: powershell

I came upon the problem where we need to compare contents two files `a.txt` and `b.txt` line by line and output the result if any difference found along with content and line number.

We should not use Compare-Object in this scenario. Do we have any alternative?

I tried using for loops but unable to get desired result

For ex : a.txt:

```
Hello = "Required"
World =  5678
Environment = "new"
Available = 9080.90
```

b.txt"

```
Hello = "Required"
World =  5678.908
Environment = "old"
Available = 6780.90
```

I need to get the output as:

```
Line number 2:World is not matching
Line number 3:Environment is not matching
Line number 4:Available is not matching
```

I tried with the following code snippet but was unsuccessful

```
$file1  = Get-Content "C:\Users\Desktop\a.txt"
$file2  = Get-Content "C:\Users\Desktop\b.txt"
$result = "C:\Users\Desktop\result.txt"

$file1 | foreach { 
$match = $file2 -match $_
    if ( $match ){ 
        $match | Out-File -Force $result -Append 
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using for loop trying to compare contents,but failed to compare

Comment: Please, add the code the above question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have an adverse reaction to `Compare-Object`, lets try this extremely janky set-up. As you have little to no requirements listed, this will give you the bare minimum to meet your conditions of 'any difference found'.

Copy and paste more `If` statements should you have more lines.

```
$a = get-content C:\a.txt
$b = get-content C:\b.txt

If($a[0] -ne $b[0]) { 
    "Line number 1:Hello is not matching" | Out-Host
}
If($a[1] -ne $b[1]) { 
    "Line number 2:World is not matching" | Out-Host
}
If($a[2] -ne $b[2]) { 
    "Line number 3:Environment is not matching" | Out-Host
}
If($a[3] -ne $b[3]) { 
    "Line number 4:Available is not matching" | Out-Host
}
```

Comment: If there are more content in the file for matching and we are considering the if statements wont it affect the performance?

Comment: 100% it will affect the performance. This is the jankiest of answers and should not be used if it is a large text file. You only provided 2 text files with 4 lines in each, no previous code or attempts and no additional data to work with. 
This answer provides nothing more and nothing less than your requested outcome and assumes that you have provided all considerations in your question, 2 .txt files and 8 lines total.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` returns the file content as an array of strings with a zero based index.

The array variable has an automatic property `.Count`/`.Length`
you can use to iterate the arrays with a simple counting for.

You need to split the line at the `=` to separate name and content.

Use [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) to output the results.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\21\SO_56231110.ps1

$Desktop = [environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
$File1   = Get-Content (Join-Path $Desktop "a.txt")
$File2   = Get-Content (Join-Path $Desktop "b.txt")

for ($i=0;$i -lt $File.Count;$i++){
    if($File1[$i] -ne $File2[$i]){
        "Line number {0}:{1} is not matching" -f ($i+1),($File1[$i] -split ' = ')[0]
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Line number 2:World is not matching
Line number 3:Environment is not matching
Line number 4:Available is not matching
```